# How to trigger drag() without dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am using jQuery UI or more specific the draggable feature. Is it possible to trigger drag() and tell the element to move/drag somewhere without doing it yourself?
Something like el.dragTo(position).

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am kinda using the draggable function as a resizer. I have a 1px thin div between two other divs. When i drag the div in either direction i resize the other two divs depending on the amount i dragged the drag-div.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `animate()`

```
$(element).animate({
    top: '10px',
    left: '30px'
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/BXVx2/

Comment: The problem is, i want to be able to drag the element and in addition i want to be able to do it automatically. The problem with animate is, i can't trigger the function that is triggered in the drag-option of my element.